# UniswapV3 swap tokens from solidity code (exactInputSingle) on Polygon TESTNET

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity

What I am doing wrong when trying to swap WMATIC to USDC using solidity code? Before calling swapExactInputSingle I am approving to spend WMATIC, however Remix still displays this error

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-or-later
pragma solidity =0.8.6;
pragma abicoder v2;

import '@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/libraries/TransferHelper.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol';

contract SingleSwap {

    ISwapRouter public immutable swapRouter = ISwapRouter(0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564);

    address public constant WMATIC = 0x9c3C9283D3e44854697Cd22D3Faa240Cfb032889;
    address public constant USDC = 0xE097d6B3100777DC31B34dC2c58fB524C2e76921;

    uint24 public constant poolFee = 3000;

    function swapExactInputSingle(uint256 amountIn) external returns (uint256 amountOut) {

        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(WMATIC, msg.sender, address(this), amountIn);

        TransferHelper.safeApprove(WMATIC, address(swapRouter), amountIn);

        ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params =
            ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams({
                tokenIn: WMATIC,
                tokenOut: USDC,
                fee: poolFee,
                recipient: msg.sender,
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountIn: amountIn,
                amountOutMinimum: 0,
                sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
            });

        amountOut = swapRouter.exactInputSingle(params);
    }
}
```

[image: Remix error]

Answer (score 0):

1 observation:
You don't need to specify *pragma abicoder v2;* since solidity > 0.8

To Troubleshoot
Try this: instead of deploying to testnet you can deploy to the HardHat node and fork the Polygon chain and make simulated transactions using preloaded test accounts.

The benefit is that you can then use console.log statement to maybe gather more information about why it's failing.

I saw a youtube tutorial by blockman codes that did a good job explaining in great detail all the steps to do so while also explaining the nuanced details that I cannot summarize succinctly here.